# Formatting Date in Freemarker to say "Today", "Yesterday", etc

Tags: date, format, freemarker

Is there a way in freemarker to compare dates to test if the date is today or yesterday... or do I have to write code in Java to do these tests?

I basically want to do this:

```
<#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 formatDate
------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<#macro formatDate date showTime=true>
    <#if date??>
        <span class="Date">
            <#if date?is_today>
                Today
            <#elseif date?is_yesterday>
                Yesterday
            <#else>
                ${date?date}
            </#if>
        </span>
        <#if showTime>
            <span class="Time">${date?time}</span>
        </#if>
    </#if>
</#macro>
```

**EDIT:** My best guess to implement this is to pass "today" and "yesterday" into the model for the pages that use this function and then compare the date values against these 2 objects in the model. I am out of out of options, but I'd rather not have to do this for every page that uses this macro. Any other options that are nicer?

```
<#if date??>
    <span class="Date">
        <#if date?date?string.short == today?date?string.short>
            Today
        <#elseif date?date?string.short == yesterday?date?string.short>
            Yesterday
        <#else>
            ${date?date}
        </#if>
    </span>
    <#if showTime>
        <span class="Time">${date?time}</span>
    </#if>
</#if>
```

Comment: Remember, Freemarker is just a template language... anything more than the simplest logic is pushing it too far.

Comment: @skaffman: Yeah I know. I really like it. To me though, I really wished it could do stuff like this - even as a built-in - because this is presentation logic type of stuff, not business logic. Putting this kind of stuff in the controllers actually bloats them.

Answer (score 13):

As the question is quite old i guess the problem vanished but anyhow, I just did it like this:

```
<#assign diff = (mydate?long / 86400000)?round - (.now?long / 86400000)?round />
```

.now is a buildin, 86400 is a constant every programmer might know and if you arent put off by ugly looks this gives you a integer diff of days. today is 0, yesterday is -1 etc.

If you would want to make ?is_today work there is a way to extend the freemarker language by implementing a TemplateDirectiveModel as outlined here:

http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/pgui_datamodel_directive.html

but i dont know yet how to actually add it to available options with the ?... notation :-)

Comment: I think you should use `?floor` instead of `?round` because `?round` will make the day change at noon instead of midnight.

Answer (score 3):

#### 1. Create utility class with following method:

```
import org.joda.time.format.*;
...
public class StringAndDateUtils {
    
    public static String yesterdayOrToday(String date) {
        DateTime dateTime = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy").parseDateTime(date);
        DateTime today = new DateTime();
        DateTime yesterday = today.minusDays(1);

        if (dateTime.toLocalDate().equals(today.toLocalDate())) {
            return "Today " ;
        } else if (dateTime.toLocalDate().equals(yesterday.toLocalDate())) {
            return "Yesterday " ;
        } else {
            return date;
        }
    }
}
```

#### 2. In your controller add the Class to your model:

```
modelMap.addAttribute("StringAndDateUtils", new StringAndDateUtils());
```

#### 3. On your .FTL pages use the method like this:

```
<#assign date = realDateObject?string("MM/dd/yyyy")/>  
${StringAndDateUtils.yesterdayOrToday(date)}
```

Comment: Cleaner than putting the logic in the controller and passing variables through the model.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the string to an int (watch out for rollovers!) and compare as per 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/freemarker/forums/forum/2345/topic/3027925?message=6479650

Be careful not exceed the maximum int value if you add extra digits like milliseconds.

(from the above link)

```
[#assign  Adate = myDateA?string("yyyyMMdd")?number?int ]
[#assign  Atime = myDateA?string("HHmmss")?number?int ]
[#assign  Bdate = myDateB?string("yyyyMMdd")?number?int ]
[#assign  Btime = myDateB?string("HHmmss")?number?int ]
```

What I did was create a TemplateMethodModel for comparing dates (Note: df is a custom thread safe SimpleDateFormatter with a timezone):

```
public BooleanModel exec(List args) throws TemplateModelException {
    int argcnt = args.size();

    if (argcnt != 3) {
        throw new TemplateModelException("Wrong arguments.  Use \"exec(Date?string(\"yyyyMMddHHmmss\"), " +
                "CompareString, Date?string(\"yyyyMMddHHmmss\"))\"," +
                " where CompareString is < = > ");
    }

    String firstDate = (String) args.get(0);
    String compareString = (String) args.get(1);
    String secondDate = (String) args.get(2);

    if (null == firstDate || null == secondDate || null == compareString ||
             compareString.length() != 1) {
        throw new TemplateModelException("Wrong arguments.  Use \"exec(Date?string(\"yyyyMMddHHmmss\"), " +
                "CompareString, Date?string(\"yyyyMMddHHmmss\"))\"," +
                " where CompareString is < = > ");
    }

    Date first = null;
    Date second = null;
    try {
        first = df.parse(firstDate);
        second = df.parse(secondDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new TemplateModelException("Wrong arguments.  Use \"exec(Date?string(\"yyyyMMddHHmmss\"), " +
                "CompareString, Date?string(\"yyyyMMddHHmmss\"))\"," +
                " where CompareString is < = > ");
    }

    if ("<".equals(compareString)) {
        return new BooleanModel(first.before(second), BeansWrapper.getDefaultInstance());
    }
    else if ("=".equals(compareString)) {
        return new BooleanModel(first.equals(second), BeansWrapper.getDefaultInstance());           
    }
    else if (">".equals(compareString)) {
        return new BooleanModel(first.after(second), BeansWrapper.getDefaultInstance());            
    }

    return new BooleanModel(Boolean.FALSE, BeansWrapper.getDefaultInstance());

}
```

In the template I call it as follows:

```
[#if compareDate(now?string("yyyyMMddHHmmss"),"<", program.resStartDateTime?string("yyyyMMddHHmmss"))]
```

FYI, "now" is a DateModel object added before template processing.

```
model.put("now", new DateModel(new Date(), BeansWrapper.getDefaultInstance()));
```

The TemplateMethodModel could be made more general by passing in a parsing string as an argument and creating the date formatter on execution.

Answer (score 0):

${houradd(date, 24)?string("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")}

${houradd(date, -24)?string("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")}

${dayadd(date, 1)?string("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")}

Comment: I cannot find this in the documentation... Is it an extension or something?